# Git LFS Error while cloning repository

Tags: git, github

How should I clone a repository that uses git LFS.

When I use the git clone command I get an error

[image]

I installed git lfs and it is in the same directory.

Thank you

Comment: and what was the command you ran?

Comment: git clone "xxx.com/Repo" C:\git\localRepo

Comment: Instead of a screenshot of your terminal, please provide the actual text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed GitHub for Windows from web and then used its commandline which worked for cloning.